# Android Studio - Kotlin Int function to string

Tags: android, kotlin

I have summary function that have two int parameters and a booelan paramater.

Here is my function

```
fun sum(s1:Int, s2:Int,str:Boolean = false) : Int{
         if (str == false){
             return s1+ s2
         } else {
             return (s1 + s2).toString()
         }
    }
```

this function returns of s1 + s2 but i have booelan paramater, if i set it to true ,my return will be s1 +s2.toString()

but i get error in toString how can i fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the function return type is strictly an `Int`. You may change that to `Any` and it will compile fine but you won't have any type safety afterwards.

As far as I know kotlin doesn't have union types as other languages do like Typescript where you could do something like:

```js
sum(a: number, b: number, str: boolean = false): number | string {
     if (str == false){
          return s1+ s2
     } else {
          return (s1 + s2).toString()
     }
}
```